# bootstrap 4 fixed height <p> and <input>'s

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working editing page on Angular2 like as the following gif. There is a height difference between the transitions and this is not good for me.

How can i fixed height with responsive and how can i change size `custom-control` (toggle/switch) ?

[image]

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="!edit; then thenTemplate; else elseTemplate"></ng-container>
    <ng-template #thenTemplate>
      <div class="row col-12" *ngIf="header && value != null ">
        <strong class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">{{header}}</strong>
        <p class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">{{onValue == value ? onText : offText}}</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #elseTemplate>
      <div class="row col-12" *ngIf="header">
        <strong class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">{{header}}</strong>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 custom-control custom-switch ">
<!-- if add thiss works normaly style="height:2.5rem"-->
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{key}}" (change)="onValueChanged($event)" [ngModel]="onValue">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{key}}">{{onValue == value ? onText : offText}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/y3KKE7PKyGIC6cDTQACD?p=preview

Comment: Try adding form-control in input type checkbox and then remove border from that, or please provide plunker so we can test it

Comment: @Aarsh added plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete working example you can find here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uokrte?file=src%2Fapp%2Feditable-toggle%2Feditable-toggle.component.html)

You just need to remove default margin which is provided to default to `p-tag`. so your `p-tag` is...

```
 <p class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 m-0">{{onValue == value ? onText : offText}} p</p>
```

So here you just need to add bootstrap margin class `m-0` to `p-tag`. and rest works as per your requirement.

Comment: `m-0` is great solution

Answer (score 0):

Set the same height for your  checkboxes and the labels after they are set.

```
 <div class="row col-12" *ngIf="same-height-class header && value != null ">
    <strong class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">{{header}}</strong>
    <p class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">{{onValue == value ? onText : offText}}</p>
  </div>
...
<div class="row col-12" *ngIf="header">
    <strong class="same-height-class col-xs-12 col-md-4">{{header}}</strong>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 custom-control custom-switch ">
```

and in css:

```
.same-height-class{
  max-height: 50px!important;
}
```

But it's quite hard to help you without a working example of the rest of the code and stlye information.

Comment: added plunker URL in question

Comment: `style="height:2.5rem"` more responsive but this is not solution i am looking for